# how to upgrade from unsupported Ubuntu version 15.04 to more recent Ubuntu version -- simply changing sources to old-releases.ubuntu.com not working

Tags: server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have a dated server running Ubuntu 15.04 that I want to update to a more recent version of Ubuntu.

On logging in, the following message is presented:

```
New release '16.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

When I run `do-release-upgrade`, I am presented with the following message:

```
An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool.
```

I checked the contents of the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and verified that upgrades are set to "normal" (i.e. the release upgrader is set to attempt to upgrade to the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running release -- as opposed to never updating or updating only to the next LTS release). Next, I attempted running `do-release-upgrade -d` to try for a development release. I was presented with the following message:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

The repositories listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` are as follows:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
```

What should I do?

---

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) because I want to upgrade to subsequent releases. The [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/654589)
 to [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) seems promising but is not working.

I have changed the repositories listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` using the following command:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This has resulted in the following listing:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
```

Then, `apt-get update` results in some hits and lots of 404s (with `apt-get upgrade` when giving the message `0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`). `do-release-upgrade`, with and without `-d` results in the same output as before.

When I check on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, the latest release I see is Utopic Unicorn 14.10. Where could Vivid Vervet 15.04 be?

What should I do?

Comment: @muru Thanks, but I am not trying to skip releases; I am trying to upgrade from an unsupported release.

Comment: Maybe change the /etc/apt/sources.list to a newer release, apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade?

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk Hey, you might be on to something there. When I check on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, the latest release I see is Utopic Unicorn 14.10. Where could Vivid Vervet 15.04 be?

Comment: @BlandCorporation Hey, I JUST looked and it's in the archive.ubuntu.com! But let me do some testing in a VM.

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk Ah, well-spotted! How did you find this site? I didn't see it mentioned in standard Ubuntu documentation. Still, though, when I change `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to archive.ubuntu.com, the upgrade from Vivid to Wily isn't working. I feel like the answer is near...

Comment: I'm giving `sed -i 's/vivid/wily/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` a shot.

Comment: @BlandCorporation Did it work? Right now, I'm trying if this works in a VM.