# `do-release-upgrade` still trying to use archives instead of old-releases

Tags: 16.04, apt, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04.  I am aware that the `archive.ubuntu.com` repositories do not contain packages for the unsupported release of 15.04.  I changed the `sources.list` files under `/etc/apt/` to use `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.  While commands like `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` now work fine, I still cannot do `sudo do-release-upgrade` -- I get `Not Found` errors as the `do-release-upgrade` is still trying to use `archive.ubuntu.com`.  How can this be?!

Are there other files I need to update to point towards `old-releases`?

Answer (score 5):

The configuration files for the update manager must also be updated!

If upgrading from an unsupported version of Ubuntu like I was, change the repositories in `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release` to point to the `old-releases` repositories.  E.g. for upgrade from 15.10,

- make sure you have successfully run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` with appropriate repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- find `Dist: wily` inside `meta-release` (substitute "wily" with your version name if updating from other unsupported release)
- replace `http://archive.ubuntu.com/...` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/...` each time it appears in the block corresponding to the release
- now run `sudo do-release-upgrade`

---

A similar question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938009/how-to-upgrade-from-unsupported-ubuntu-version-15-04-to-more-recent-ubuntu-versi) -- though no official answer is given.  The question is marked as a duplicate, but neither it nor the questions it links to answer this issue of modifying the `update-manager` configuration.